# SQL Checking if a value exists in any column and return the value listed of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how I can run a query to check and see if someone is listed under someone else. An example would be like a team. There is a team leader and people under that leader. I need to run a query to see if a name is listed under someone else.

I have a table with the following columns:

- **ID**;
- **Leader_FirstName**;
- **Leader_LastName**;
- **Member1_FN**;
- **Member1_LN**;
- **Member2_FN**;
- **Member2_LN**, etc...

I need to check the whole table and if that name exist as any of the members it would return the value of `Leader_FirstName` and `Leader_LastName`.

I've been trying to use a "WHERE EXISTS" Like:

```
SELECT * FROM team
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM team
                WHERE Member1_FN = '$member_fName' AND Member1_LN = '$member_lName'
                   OR Member2_FN = '$member_fName' AND Member2_LN = '$member_lName'
                   OR ... etc...
              )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's an idea: normalize the data model. Instead of separate columns for Member1_, Member2_, Member3_, etc.  use a second table with a separate row for each member.  In terms of your current model, remove this part from your query ... `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM team WHERE`.

Comment: That's a normalization problem. I forget which normal form it is, but you should not have repetition in a record like that.

Comment: Can a leader of one team be a member of another? If yes, see nested sets. If no, see adjacency lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, for this data model, one row records one leader and all members, there is no good way to query it.

```
SELECT * FROM team
WHERE (Member1_FN = '$member_fName' AND Member1_LN = '$member_lName')
      OR (Member2_FN = '$member_fName' AND Member2_LN = '$member_lName')
      OR (... etc...
```

This is equivalent to your SQL, but **not good**.

I think, this table structure is unreasonable. The number of columns in the table depends on the maximum number of members of the leader. If add some members, you must change the table structure to add some columns. It is not flexible enough.

There are many methods to optimize the structure.

**1. One row with one member**

Table `team` with the following columns:

- ID
- Leader_FirstName
- Leader_LastName
- Member_FN
- Member_LN

Leader info will record at many rows, this is the major disadvantage for this structure. In order to avoid this problem, you can try follow method.

**2. Two tables: `leader` and `member`**

Table `leader` with following columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName

Table `member` with following columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- LeaderID

Now, you can join `leader` and `member` to find the leader of members.

**3. One table `team` with relationship**

Table `team` is same with the `member` as follow:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- LeaderID (For leader is NULL)

Now, join `team` and itself.

Use above structure, how to query? I think, you can concat the FirstName and LastName with an separator char that does not appear in the name to a string, than use `IN` to compare it, for example:

For 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM team 
WHERE CONCAT_WS(',', Member_FN, Member_LN) 
    IN (CONCAT_WS(',', '$member1_fName', '$member1_fName'), 
        CONCAT_WS(',', '$member2_fName', '$member2_fName'),
        ...etc...)
```

For 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM leader, member 
WHERE leader.ID = member.LeaderId and CONCAT_WS(',', member.FirstName, member.LastName) 
    IN (CONCAT_WS(',', '$member1_fName', '$member1_fName'), 
        CONCAT_WS(',', '$member2_fName', '$member2_fName'),
        ...etc...)
```

For 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM team a, team b 
WHERE a.ID = b.LeaderId and CONCAT_WS(',', b.FirstName, b.LastName) 
    IN (CONCAT_WS(',', '$member1_fName', '$member1_fName'), 
        CONCAT_WS(',', '$member2_fName', '$member2_fName'),
        ...etc...)
```

Comment: There are further methods

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM team
 WHERE (Member1_FN = '$member_fName' AND Member1_LN = '$member_lName')
                   OR (Member2_FN = '$member_fName' AND Member2_LN = '$member_lName')
                   OR (... etc...
```